# Periodic workspace save internal error eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, save

I am constantly getting this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz89J.png)

```
An internal error occurred during: "Periodic workspace save.".
Cannot set lower sequence number for root (previous: 4, new: 2). Location: /Users/LeoG/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources
```

I am using Eclipse Luna for mac
Please tell me if this is anything bad, and if possible, how to get rid of it
All help is appreciated :D

Comment: What are you doing that generates this error?

Comment: There is a discussion of this in Eclipse bug [415014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415014)

Comment: @FishStix Nothing, I usually leave eclipse open and I do something else, then when I come back I have 1 or more of these errors. So I guess eclipse or java saves you project every few mins

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, but that doesn't tell me how to solve it :(

Comment: It appears to be a bug in Eclipse which means there may not be a work around.  The bug is closed and the last line indicates that if this happens in 4.5, a user should re-open the new bug.  Luna, the version you're using is 4.4.  The solution is to update Eclipse to 4.5 (Mars).

Comment: @FishStix Thanks!, Instead of having to constantly update eclipse (As i've already done once before) So, correct me if I'm wrong, but updating to the most recent version should just fix a bunch of stuff in the future, so what would the latest version of every eclipse be?

Comment: Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) looks to be the latest version right now.  I would recommend updating to that one.

Comment: All of the neon mac versions are for 64bit, I have 32 bit, Should I still just get the 64bit?

Answer (score -1):

For this you need to configure the build path of your project. You probably achieve this if you move your project files into your eclipse work space. Click on the project in eclipse -> "Build Path >> Configure Build Path >>" now set up jre system library, if its already present then delete that and add a new jre library (from directory of program files). happy coding!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I no longer use eclipse, but hopefully this should help someone else having that problem! Happy coding to you as well!